# Lua - Split CSV Column at Hyphen

Tags: csv, parsing, lua, lua-table

I want to use the Lua CSV http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaCsv
and need to split one of the columns that use a hyphen "-" eg: First-Surname into the table it creates. I can do it manually in excel with Data > Text to Columns, that will split the Full-Name cell and add a First and a Surname column to the end, I need Lua to do the same in the script:

```
Before
Age,Name,Start,End,Length,Score
35,Bill-Smith,2.2.2017,2.4.2017,0.2.00,2056

After
Age,Name,Start,End,Length,Score,First,Surname
35,Bill-Smith,2.2.2017,2.4.2017,0.2.00,2056,Bill,Smith
```

This is the Lua csv parser to be used:

```
function ParseCSVLine (line,sep) 
    local res = {}
    local pos = 1
    sep = sep or ','
    while true do 
        local c = string.sub(line,pos,pos)
        if (c == "") then break end
        if (c == '"') then
            -- quoted value (ignore separator within)
            local txt = ""
            repeat
                local startp,endp = string.find(line,'^%b""',pos)
                txt = txt..string.sub(line,startp+1,endp-1)
                pos = endp + 1
                c = string.sub(line,pos,pos) 
                if (c == '"') then txt = txt..'"' end 
                -- check first char AFTER quoted string, if it is another
                -- quoted string without separator, then append it
                -- this is the way to "escape" the quote char in a quote. example:
                --   value1,"blub""blip""boing",value3  will result in blub"blip"boing  for the middle
            until (c ~= '"')
            table.insert(res,txt)
            assert(c == sep or c == "")
            pos = pos + 1
        else    
            -- no quotes used, just look for the first separator
            local startp,endp = string.find(line,sep,pos)
            if (startp) then 
                table.insert(res,string.sub(line,pos,startp-1))
                pos = endp + 1
            else
                -- no separator found -> use rest of string and terminate
                table.insert(res,string.sub(line,pos))
                break
            end 
        end
    end
    return res
end
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What Piglet said.  It's unclear exactly what your problem/question is here.

Comment: The csv's have a name string with a - in the middle. I need Lua to split that cell at the hyphen ,adding them to two new cells in the table. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-30B14928-5550-41F5-97CA-7A3E9C363ED7

Comment: Why not use a library? Like lua-csv: https://github.com/geoffleyland/lua-csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the second value per row is always the name, and always contains the first-last hyphen separator as the first or only hyphen in the name (not necessarily a safe assumption), then you can read each line in from your input (I've used a string, but this could be an IO reader or whatever you're using), parse out the second value using patterns into a first and last name, append them to the end of the read line and then write it back (I'm inserting it into a table here for demonstration):

```
local input = [[
35,Bill-Smith,2.2.2017,2.4.2017,0.2.00,2056
31,Ben-Smith,2.4.2015,2.6.2012,0.2.01,2058
32,Bob-Smith,2.3.2016,2.7.2011,0.2.02,2057
]]

local output = {}

for line in string.gmatch (input, '[^\010\014]+') do --get next group of letters up to the next CR or LF character
    local name = string.match (line, '^.-,(.-),') -- assuming that the name field is always the second value here
    local first, last = string.match (name or '', '^(.-)%-(.+)$')
    line = line .. ',' .. (first or '') .. ',' .. (last or name or '')
    table.insert (output, line)
end

print (table.concat (output, '\r\n'))

>>>>>>>
35,Bill-Smith,2.2.2017,2.4.2017,0.2.00,2056,Bill,Smith
31,Ben-Smith,2.4.2015,2.6.2012,0.2.01,2058,Ben,Smith
32,Bob-Smith,2.3.2016,2.7.2011,0.2.02,2057,Bob,Smith
```